# How to replace SQL Server sys.all_objects in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I am working on migrating SQL Server views to Postgres. I faced a big issue: how can I get all the objects (user-defined and system objects of a database like using `sys.all_objects`) in Postgres?

I need all the views, functions, procedure extended procedure object id, creation time and modification time. What is the equivalent for `sys.all_objects` in Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

> I need all the views, functions, procedure extended procedure object id

There is no single view/table that contains everything in the [system catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html).

You need to combine [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html), [pg_proc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html) and probably [pg_type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html)

> creation time and modification time

This information is not recorded or stored in PostgreSQL, so there is no way to get that from the system catalogs.